# Table inside a div - horizontal scrollbar only at the bottom of the div

Tags: scrollbar

I have a big table inside a div that has a overflow-auto defined. Still I can get only a vertical scrollbar visible. The horizontal scrollbar is at the bottom at the div, which makes it quite inconvenient to use. Any ideas what is happening here?!

Comment: Some code please to demonstrate your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
$("#scrollbar").on("scroll", function(){
  var container = $("#container");
  var scrollbar = $("#scrollbar");
  
  ScrollUpdate(container, scrollbar);
});

function ScrollUpdate(content, scrollbar){
    $("#spacer").css({"width":"500px"}); // set the spacer width
    scrollbar.width = content.width() + "px";
    content.scrollLeft(scrollbar.scrollLeft());
}

ScrollUpdate($("#container"),$("#scrollbar"));

$("#tab").tableHeadFixer({
  "left": 1,
  "right": 0,
  "head": true
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  overflow-x: hidden !important;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

#scrollbar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 10;
}

#spacer {
  height: 1px;
}

#tab {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: #CCCCCC;
}

tr,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="scrollbar"><div id="spacer"></div></div>

<div id="container">
  <table id="tab">
    <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Title</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>History</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>test</td>
     <td>test</td>
     <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>test</td>
     <td>test</td>
     <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>test</td>
     <td>test</td>
     <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>test</td>
     <td>test</td>
     <td>test</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: But here is the same problem that I have. User have to scroll down the div to have the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: Now this looks exactly what I was looking for! Still have to study where and how to implement that javascript function. But for now big thanks!

Comment: If you are already using an $(document).ready(function(){}); you can put it in there. Otherwise you could put it at the bottom of your page just before your </body> and put it inside <script></script> tags. Also if this is an accepted answer please check accepted so other can find the answer quickly.

Comment: It works perfectly if it is the only javascript function on the page. Still have the problem with other javascript functions. I can't get them all to work :/

Comment: by doesnt work do you mean the bottom scroll bar disappears when using tableHeadFixer? or is there an error in the console?

Comment: Ok, updated the code to work with tableHeadFixer. All you need to do is ad a height to the container div and overflow-x:hidden !important; Check the answer for the code. You will need to add the tableHeadFixer js because there is no cdn link for it.

Comment: I need to use actually tableHeadFixer function to lock the first column of the table. My code:  $("#mytable").tableHeadFixer({"head": true, "left": 1, "right": 0});   And then for some reason I can't lock the header with this, so I use floatHead function to lock the header: $("#mytable").floatThead({zIndex: 1}); So when I have both these lines then when I use the scroll bar the table moves just a very little but not until the end. If I remove the floatHead line, then the scroll bar works perfectly with first column locked.

Comment: I added the tableHeadFixer to the top of my code. It works for me. The first column is locked and the header is also locked. If you copy my code to a fresh page of yours and only include my code and required jquery/tableHeadFixer js then you can see it working. If you need a more detailed debugging you will need to post an error log or the code you are using.

Comment: I solved this jquery problem. I have so many different functions on the same page so there were some conflicts. But now this works PERFECTLY. Thank you so so much!